# How to create a trigger in Azure Data Factory which triggers once file available in ADLS

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I have a web app where some python code is running which generates csv files and stores it in ADLS ,I wanted to have ADF pipeline which triggers when files arrives in ADLS and load data into DB.
I wanted to know is there any automated triggering facility available in ADF as my files will be based on user input from a front end tool and we do not have idea when user will generate the files it can be very random.I went through Event based triggering option but it says that only 500 triggers are allowed per storage account but in our case there might be more that 500 in single day. Is there any way to achieve the trigger or am I understanding 500 triggers as something wrong.Any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

- Azure Data Factory only supports a maximum of 500 event triggers per storage account, it means that you can only create  a maximum of 500 event triggers per storage account.
- When you created an event trigger for the pipeline, the trigger times  up to your quantity of the created files and it is not limited.

I've made a test here that shows one pipeline can be triggered more than 500 times in one day:

[image]